# Conditional Probability Prove or Disprove

Tags: probability

Given P(A|B∪C)≥min(P(A|B),P(A|C)), prove or disprove the statement. My intuition said that the statement should be correct, however I can't think of a mathematical way of proving this statement. Any suggestion is highly appreciated

Comment: If you are **given** P(A|B∪C)≥min(P(A|B),P(A|C)), what is there to prove or disprove?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
A B C Prob
0 1 0 0.2
0 0 1 0.2
1 1 1 0.6
```

Then $\Pr(A|B)=\Pr(A|C)=0.6/0.8 = 0.75$

but $\Pr(A|B \cup C) = 0.6/1.0 = 0.6$.

So the statement is not always true.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer

Comment: @TearGrant: don't forget to 
1. upvote an answer (an uparrow to the left of the answer) if you like it and 
2. accept it (check sign, also to the left)